# Singly-linked list issues with delete function along with sorting via strcmp C/C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, sorting, singly-linked-list

My singly linked list consists of `char *id; char firstname[15]; char lastname[15]; struct rec *next;`.

So my main issue that I am having in this assignment is deleting a record via passing the ID into the delete function. It will delete the ID but the second it get to the line to delete either firstname or lastname it throws this error.

> `"ChristmasList.exe has triggered a breakpoint. occurred"`.

My second main error is that my `strcmp` always compares the same string so it will always return 0, I am also a little shakey on how to do this anyways so even if it returned -1 or 1. I don't know if it would sort properly.

Thank you to anyone that can offer help, I have been stuck on this problem for a long time and need to fix it before we get our next lab assigned as we are adding to this code.

Main:

```
// ChristmasList.cpp : Adds, Deletes, and prints items in a structured list
// MyName

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "list.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    rec myRec; // pointer to rec structure
    int choice = 1; // initializing so choice is not 0 to start
    int order; // ascending/descending input
    char buf[500]; // buffer array
    int result; //result of function calls
    while (choice != 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter 1 to Add an Item.\n";
        cout << "Enter 2 to delete  a record.\n";
        cout << "Enter 3 to Print a list of records.\n";
        cout << "Enter 0 to exit the program\n";
        cin >> choice; // User input for choice
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: //Add
            cout << "Enter your ID: "; //ask to enter ID
            cin >> buf; //Input for ID into rec
            myRec.id = buf;
            cout << "Enter your first name: "; // Ask for first name
            cin >> myRec.firstname; // Input first name into rec
            cout << "Enter your last name: "; // Ask for last name
            cin >> myRec.lastname; // Input last name into rec
            if (AddItem(myRec)) // Call Add
            {
                cout << "Success\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nFailed to add :(\n";
            }
                break;

        case 2: //Delete
            cout << "Enter the ID of the record you want to delete: "; // ask to enter ID that wants to be deleted
            cin >> buf; // Input id wanting to be deleted
            result = DeleteItem(buf); // Call delete
                break;
        case 3: //Print
            cout << "Enter 0 for ascending order and 1 for descending order: "; // ask for ascending or descending
            cin >> order; // User input for ascending or descending
            PrintList(order); // Call Print
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

list.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "list.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

rec *first = NULL;
rec *last = NULL;
int counter = 0;
rec *MyNewRec2[500];

int AddItem(rec r)
{
    int comp;
    int comp2;
    rec *MyNewRec;
    MyNewRec = new rec;
    MyNewRec->id = new char[10];
    strcpy_s(MyNewRec->id, strlen(r.id) + 1, r.id); // Copying ID
    strcpy_s(MyNewRec->firstname, strlen(r.firstname) + 1, r.firstname);// Copying first name 
    strcpy_s(MyNewRec->lastname, strlen(r.lastname) + 1, r.lastname);// Copying last name

    while (first != NULL)
    {
        if (*MyNewRec->id == *first->id)
        {
            cout << "Duplicate ID: " << MyNewRec->id << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            MyNewRec2[counter] = MyNewRec;
            last = MyNewRec2[counter];
            first = first->next;
            counter++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (first == NULL) // If no items are in the list
    {
        MyNewRec->next = NULL;
        first = MyNewRec;
        last = MyNewRec;
        MyNewRec2[counter] = MyNewRec;
        counter++;
    }
    if (r.lastname >= "97")
    {
        char *temp;
        temp = r.lastname - 32;
    }
    comp = strcmp(MyNewRec->lastname, (first->lastname - 1));
    comp2 = strcmp(MyNewRec->lastname, (last->lastname - 1));
    if (comp == -1 && comp <= 0) //Move first back in array
    {
        MyNewRec2[counter - 1] = NULL;
        MyNewRec2[counter - 1] = MyNewRec;
        MyNewRec->next = first;
        first = MyNewRec;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (comp2 == 1 && comp2 >= 0) //Move last back in array
    {
        MyNewRec->next = NULL;
        last->next = last;
        MyNewRec2[counter -1] = last;
        last = MyNewRec;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (first->next != NULL)
        {
            comp = strcmp(MyNewRec->lastname, first->lastname);
            if (comp == 1)
            {
                first = first->next;
                return 1;
            }
            else if (comp == 1 || comp == 0)
            {
                MyNewRec2[counter - 1] = first;
                MyNewRec->next = first->next;
                first->next = MyNewRec;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
    }
    int DeleteItem(char *delid)
    {
    rec *MyNewRec, *temp;
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    while (first != NULL)
    {
        if (*first->id == *delid)
        {
            MyNewRec = first->next;
            //temp = MyNewRec2[counter - 1]; // Random try
            //temp->next = MyNewRec; // Random try
            delete[] first->id;
            delete[] first->firstname;
            delete[] first->lastname;
            delete first;
            counter--;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
    void PrintList(int order)
    {
    rec *temp = new rec;
    if (order == 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        temp = MyNewRec2[i];
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout.flush() << temp->id << " ";
            cout.flush() << temp->firstname << " ";
            cout.flush() << temp->lastname << " " << endl;
            i++;
            temp = MyNewRec2[i];
        }
    }
    temp = MyNewRec2[counter - 1];
    if (order == 1)
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout.flush() << temp->id << " ";
            cout.flush() << temp->firstname << " ";
            cout.flush() << temp->lastname << " " << endl;
            counter--;
            temp = MyNewRec2[counter - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

list.h:

```
struct rec
{
    char *id;
    char firstname[15];
    char lastname[15];
    struct rec *next;
};

int AddItem(rec r);
int DeleteItem(char *delid);
void PrintList(int order);
```

Comment: I changed the tag from C to C++ since you are using `new` and `delete`

Answer (score 0):

This is your struct:

```
struct rec
{
    char *id;
    char firstname[15];
    char lastname[15];
    struct rec *next;
};
```

This is how you allocated memory for the new record:

```
MyNewRec = new rec;
MyNewRec->id = new char[10];
```

And this is how you deallocated it.

```
        delete[] first->id;
        delete[] first->firstname;
        delete[] first->lastname;
```

`firstname` and `lastname` members are not pointers that you allocated.  They are fixed arrays that were allocated when `rec` was allocated via new.  Or put it another way, if you didn't `new` it, then you don't `delete` it.

Remove these two lines:

```
        delete[] first->firstname;
        delete[] first->lastname;
```

I don't have time to debug the rest of the code, but I'll just say this.  These next line looks weird and incorrect:

```
comp = strcmp(MyNewRec->lastname, (first->lastname - 1));
comp2 = strcmp(MyNewRec->lastname, (last->lastname - 1));
```

I don't get the `-1` thing.  But I gotta run....

Comment: For the assignment I HAVE to delete both first name and last name. I added this to my code: *MyNewRec->firstname = *new char;
 *MyNewRec->lastname = *new char;  But it still throws the same error when i try to deallocate first and lastname. Im sorry this looks so shitty, this is my first stackoverflow

Comment: And the reason for the -1 thing is because first->lastname was giving the same lastname as MyNewRec->lastname so I wanted to get the last name of the record behind it... As you can probably tell this is my first time really working with singly linked lists and structures.

Comment: @LonePuma - you can't `delete` what you didn't `new`.  Keep saying that until you believe it.  You can however convert `firstname` and `lastname` from fixed length array members to pointers. Then have your code `new` to allocate firstname and lastname.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I also did that. It keeps throwing the error, I think it's something as simple as having a * somewhere where it shouldn't be.